# Golang UnmarshalXML & MarshalXML identity

Tags: xml, go

I UnmarshalXML xml, but I can't get the same result when MarshalXML (see the example below). As you can see the **xs:simpleType** is transformed into a **simpleType** and other differences. How can I make a complete identity? I need to convert arbitrary xml according to certain rules, so I can't use specific tags.

You can view the working code here: https://play.golang.org/p/QK2AfPsR9ZN

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var data = []byte(`
<xs:simpleType name="x"></xs:simpleType>
`)

type Node struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Attrs   []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
    Content []byte     `xml:",innerxml"`
    Nodes   []Node     `xml:",any"`
}

func (n *Node) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    n.Attrs = start.Attr
    type node Node
    return d.DecodeElement((*node)(n), &start)
}

func (n *Node) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    n.Attrs = start.Attr
    type node Node
    return e.EncodeElement((*node)(n), start)
}

func main() {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    dec := xml.NewDecoder(buf)
    var n Node
    dec.Decode(&n)
    output, _ := xml.Marshal(n)
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

Output:

```
<simpleType xmlns="xs" name="x" name="x"></simpleType>
```

Comment: You don't need custom marshaling or unmarshaling logic, and you can force this behavior if before marshaling you concatenate the namespace and tag name: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4vIcTW0w0Yl). Does this answer your question?

Comment: @icza thanks for the advice. But if i try to use this XML https://play.golang.org/p/ECIeA35BOpW - incoming and printed XML is different. Why?

Comment: Because my example did not change the names of child nodes. You have to do that recursively. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need custom marshaling or unmarshaling logic, and you can force this behavior if before marshaling you concatenate the namespace and tag name:

```
n.XMLName.Local = n.XMLName.Space + ":" + n.XMLName.Local
n.XMLName.Space = ""
```

Example input matches output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4vIcTW0w0Yl)):

```
<xs:simpleType name="x" other="y">Some content</xs:simpleType>
```

Of course if there are child tags, you have to process names of all nodes recursively. Let's write a helper for that:

```
func setName(n *Node) {
    n.XMLName.Local = n.XMLName.Space + ":" + n.XMLName.Local
    n.XMLName.Space = ""

    for i := range n.Nodes {
        setName(&n.Nodes[i])
    }
}
```

Example XML input:

```
<xs:simpleType name="comma-separated-integer">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>The comma-separated-integer element.</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
    <xs:pattern value="[1-9][0-9]*(, ?[1-9][0-9]*)*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Using the helper:

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
dec := xml.NewDecoder(buf)
var n Node
if err := dec.Decode(&n); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

setName(&n)

output, err := xml.Marshal(n)
fmt.Println(string(output))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Then output almost matches the input. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Dnv8u5gnEio).

The problem is: the inner content is duplicated. This is because `Node.Content` is the inner XML content, and child tags are also added as child nodes to `Node.Nodes`. So to get the same output, child nodes doesn't need to be marshalled, `Content` already contains the children.

Remove the duplication by clearning `Nodes`:

```
n.XMLName.Local = n.XMLName.Space + ":" + n.XMLName.Local
n.XMLName.Space = ""
n.Nodes = nil
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6BycNE6YFdD).

Note: if you intend to manipulate the XML child nodes, this isn't a viable option. Then you may keep the `setName()` helper function, and to remove the duplication, you may zero the `Content` of the nodes that have child nodes:

```
func setName(n *Node) {
    n.XMLName.Local = n.XMLName.Space + ":" + n.XMLName.Local
    n.XMLName.Space = ""
    if len(n.Nodes) != 0 {
        n.Content = nil
    }

    for i := range n.Nodes {
        setName(&n.Nodes[i])
    }
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c4XCVlSeJja).

Comment: I think you need to add: if len(n.Nodes) != 0 {n.Content = nil} into setName function, because <xs:documentation> content missing. https://play.golang.org/p/_K7IvGakL9B

Comment: @nrw2000 Yes, you're right, was working on it. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

In our team we have been using for a few months a fantastic module that expresses XML inspired by Python etrees.

https://github.com/beevik/etree

It's simple but very powerful to interpret and manipulate XMLs.